# Удаление временных файлов на хостинге

Tags: хостинг, ispmanager

Если удалить все временные файлы это никак не повлияет на работу сайта?
Хочу удалить все папки с названием tmp, одну папку с названием bin-tmp уже удалил.
Пока сайт работает нормально.

На скрине снизу остались две папки: это **mod-tmp и aps_tmp, я их отметил красным.**
⠀⠀⠀⠀ **Можно ли удалить эти две папки без страшных последствий для сайта?**

Сильно не ругайтесь, я впервые управляю хостингом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну переименуйте вы эту папку или заархивируйте. Посмотрите, не лег ли сайт. Если не лег - стирайте.

Comment: А зачем вообще нужны эти временные файлы и почему они так много занимают места?

Comment: @Хлебушек для этого лучше создать отдельный вопрос, так в комментарии это не напишешь так просто.

Comment: А никто не знает, что у вас там. Как правило, там располагается некий кэш - статическая репрезентация некоей динамической страницы, контент которой не изменился. Такой подход используется для экономии ресурсов и увеличения скорости загрузки. А еще там могут быть файлы сессий, временный контент подгружаемых сторонних ресурсов, внутренние файлы статистики и прочее.

Comment: Ну если удалить все это дело сайт не ляжет?

Comment: Еще раз: перед тем, как пить таблетки, лучше почитать инструкцию. Читайте мой первый комментарий - переименуйте директорию или заархивируйте. Потом смотрите, ляжет или нет. Одно из правил IT - всегда делать бекап перед удалением. Эта привычка сохранит вам нервы и карьеру в будущем.

Comment: Ух, спс вам большое